# what is the purpose of snapshot testing in react

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I recently started to write tests for my components, one type of the tests that I've found called "[Snapshot Testing](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#snapshot-testing)"

I was wondering what is the purpose of this kind of testing?

it passes the first time and fails when some changes occur in the render method.

I sense it has no benefit since the UI can change many times.

Comment: what if the change is unintended in same component? or another component? You can regenerate the snapshots if it's an intentional change then it would pass again.

Comment: The main issue with snapshot testing is that it test the implementation details, so you can break your test by updating a classname even if your logic and UI stay the same. Here is a good article about snapshot testing: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/effective-snapshot-testing

Answer (score 0):

It takes a snapshot of your UI component structure and makes sure the structure is the same after you modifying the UI component. The modification looks don't affect the UI component structure, but it does.

Although we can assert whether a UI component is rendered, we hard to see the whole structure for the nested component. snapshot testing is a convenient way to do this.